# backup data for reporting

Tags: sql-server, database

What is the best method to transfer data from sales table to sales history table in sql server 2005. sales history table will be used for reporting.

Comment: A backup is not suppossed to be used for reporting (or anything else), but it should be kept in a safe place. 

I suggest to change that word with 'Copy'.

Answer (score 1):

Bulkcopy is fast and it will not use the transaction log. One batch run at the end of the day.

Deleting the copied records from your production server is a different situation that needs to be planed on that server's maintenance approach/plans. Your reporting server solution should not interfere with or affect the production server.

Keep in mind that your reporting server is not meant to be a backup of the data but rather a copy made exclusively for reporting purposes.

Also check on the server settings of your reporting server to be on [Simple recovery model](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SSAS.  OLAP is built for reporting and is easy to query with tools like excel pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions will require 2 steps;
-copy the records from source to target
-delete records from source.
It is essential that your source table have a primary key.

The "best" method depends on a lot of things.
How many records? 
Is this a production environment? 
What tools do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are moving a large amount of data, a simple stored procedure should do the trick. 
A [sql server job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) can manage the timing of when to call the proc.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to move the data to another table, use BulkCopy/BulkInsert. if you want to build reporting I would suggest a BI solution such as MS Analysis Service (OLAP).

It is difficult and in my opinion ugly to maintain two or more history/archive tables in the same database. For a reporting solution you will be considering all the tables for that piece of information anyway. History/Archive tables should only be used if you are going to put the data away and not touch it for a long period of time, ie. archive it away outside the operational DB.